# Spring boot Application run failed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException-OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa, microservices, java-11

I am working on an upgrade of a spring boot application from JDK 1.8 to 11 and moving to Spring boot version: 2.4.9 from 2.0.3.RELEASE. Application build is successful but the application is failing to run with the following exception. Can anyone please help me here if any dependency is missing in my pom? I know from the error logs that OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter class is not able to find during runtime but I am not sure how to fix this issue. Please note that this application is running successfully on JDK 1.8 and Spring boot version:2.0.3.RELEASE and this issue has been as part of migration of JDK and SPring boot.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/abhiram_s/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.4/logback-classic-1.2.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/abhiram_s/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.13.3/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.13.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.9)

2021-09-09 19:31:59.952  INFO 13488 --- [           main] c.t.d.DatabaseServiceApplication         : Starting DatabaseServiceApplication using Java 11.0.10 on TVMATP273632L with PID 13488 (D:\testMicroPosPdmCodeRepo\databaseservice\target\classes started by Abhiram_S in D:\testMicroPosPdmCodeRepo\databaseservice)
2021-09-09 19:31:59.958  INFO 13488 --- [           main] c.t.d.DatabaseServiceApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-09 19:32:01.959  INFO 13488 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-09 19:32:01.979  INFO 13488 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 7 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-09-09 19:32:01.980  INFO 13488 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-09 19:32:02.086  INFO 13488 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 105 ms. Found 13 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-09-09 19:32:02.453 ERROR 13488 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration.httpPutFormContentFilter
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at com.client.databaseservice.DatabaseServiceApplication.main(DatabaseServiceApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1147) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:194) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:170) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:163) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.lambda$updateTypesIfNecessary$2(BeanTypeRegistry.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:148) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:114) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:265) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:254) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:196) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:116) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/filter/OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 43 common frames omitted

2021-09-09 19:32:02.510  WARN 13488 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:903) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:891) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:878) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:819) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:349) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at com.client.databaseservice.DatabaseServiceApplication.main(DatabaseServiceApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/filter/OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

**Attaching both parent pom and child pom files here:
parent pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.client.parentpom</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <name>parent-pom</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <build.number>RELEASE</build.number>
        <spring.version>2.4.9</spring.version>
        <jaxb.version>2.3.0</jaxb.version>
        <kubernetes.version>1.1.9.RELEASE</kubernetes.version>
        <spring-client.version>3.0.4</spring-client.version>
        <swagger-annotations.version>1.5.0</swagger-annotations.version>
        <jackson-threetenbp.version>2.6.4</jackson-threetenbp.version>
        <json.version>20180813</json.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.2</junit.version>
        <javax.activation.version>2.0.1.Final</javax.activation.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-client.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-threetenbp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
            <version>${kubernetes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.activation.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**child pom file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>databaseservice</artifactId>
    <version>${APP_PREFIX}-${APP_VERSION}.${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>databaseservice</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.client.parentpom</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId> <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId> 
                </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency> <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId> <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId> 
            <version>3.2.0</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_pushgateway</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_hotspot</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Generating classes from swagger files -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>posPdmService-api</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>src/main/resources/swaggers/DatabaseServiceSwagger_v1.0.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>spring</language>
                            <configOptions>
                                <modelPackage>com.client.databaseservice.swagger.service.models</modelPackage>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                            </configOptions>
                            <output>${basedir}</output>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Generating classes from XSD files - JDK 11 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source-for-blob</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/blob.xsd</source>
                            </sources>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                            <schemaFiles>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/blob.xsd</schemaFiles>
                            <packageName>com.client.databaseservice.jaxb.blob.models</packageName>
                            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- Generating classes from xsd files - JDK 1.8 -->
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source-for-blob</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>blob.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <generateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>com.client.databaseservice.jaxb.blob.models</generatePackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

**Again, I updated the child pom with the version for below dependency and was getting following exception**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.9</version>
            <!-- <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>
```

```
Application failed to start due to an exception

javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:291) ~[validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory.getObject(MessageInterpolatorFactory.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator$Delegate.<init>(ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.java:68) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.<init>(ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.java:41) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.getJsr303Validator(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:150) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.getValidators(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.getBindHandler(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:109) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:90) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:89) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:78) ~[spring-boot-2.4.9.jar:2.4.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
```

Comment: "Can anyone please help me here if any dependency is missing in my pom?" I guess you forget to include your pom.

Comment: It seems that you have different Spring Boot versions in your classpath, see e.g. `spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar` vs `spring-boot-2.4.9.jar`…

Comment: @samabcde Yeah I missed updating the pom files. I've attached those. Please have a look.

Comment: @slauth I've updated spring-boot-autoconfigure to 2.4.9 version but I am getting below error on my STS console: ```javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:291) ~[validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar```

Comment: Try adding `spring-boot-starter-validation`

Comment: @slauth Tried adding spring-boot-starter-validation but got below run time exception  `ValidationAutoConfiguration#defaultValidator matched-@ConditionalOnMissingBean (types:javax.validation.Validator;SearchStrategy:all)did not findany beans(OnBeanCondition),ValidationAutoConfiguration#methodValidationPostProcessor matched-@ConditionalOnMissingBean(types:org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor;SearchStrategy:all)did not find anybeans (OnBeanCondition)Causedby:org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerExceptio:UnabletostartembeddedTomcat:spring-boot-2.4.9`